# From recursion to iteration (loop)

Tags: c

How do you translate the following recursion to iteration in C?

Example:

```
int sum(int n) {
    return n < 2 ? n : sum(n-1) + sum(n-2);
}
```

Comment: Google: Fibonacci numbers

Comment: By choosing a better algorithm, preferably. The naive Fibonacci computation isn't easily transformed into a loop.

Comment: What did you try? What is the equation computed by `sum`?

Comment: This is a question. But not a real one.

Comment: http://www.notes.onwid.com/program-to-print-fibonacci-series/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Directly apply the definition of [Fibonacci series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number):

[image: reg]

[image: ini]

To get a 1:1 translation:

```
int f(int N) {
    int fn = N; // Edit: init fn with N
    int fn_1 = 1;
    int fn_2 = 0;
    while (N >= 2) {
        fn = fn_1 + fn_2;
        fn_2 = fn_1;
        fn_1 = fn;
        N--;
    }
    return fn;
}
```

Comment: ,what if you have n = 1? then this ftn will return 0 isn't it?

Comment: @IMPERFECT Yes, and indeed `fibo[1]` is defined as `1`. Just initialize `fn` with `N` to get the correct result.